# Package glossaries - single spaced \printglossaries?

Tags: line-spacing, glossaries

I'm trying to make a single-spaced glossary using the glossaries package but it seems as though the package has a default level of spacing in between entries even in single-spaced mode for the document. I'm using the [ut-thesis](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/ut-thesis/) style, which is based on report.cls. Examples below. Double-spaced text:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{ut-thesis}
…
\usepackage[nonumberlist]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries
…
\begin{document}
\printglossaries
…
\end{document}
```

[image: double]

Single-spaced text:

```
\documentclass[11pt,singlespaced]{ut-thesis}
…
\usepackage[nonumberlist]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries
…
\begin{document}
\printglossaries
…
\end{document}
```

[image: single]

This is simply not single-spaced enough for my purposes. I checked the documentation for glossaries and I hope I didn't miss anything there but nothing for `\printglossaries` or otherwise seemed to indicate that spacing could be altered. I tried using the leading package to help my case. This is the best that I could come up with:

```
\documentclass[11pt,singlespaced]{ut-thesis}
…
\usepackage{leading}
\usepackage[nonumberlist]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries
…
\begin{document}
\leading{10pt}
\printglossaries
…
\end{document}
```

[image: leading]

It works okay and it's what I'm using right now but I'm not sure why I can't get it to be any better. Any ideas?

Also, I'm a bit new here so if someone feels like correcting my taxonomy with respect to tagging this question, please feel free.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Given the default glossary entry "style" isn't what you want, why not select another one via the `\printglossary` style options (e.g., `\printglossary[style=altlist]`)? The manual sets out quite a few styles that might work for you.

Out of these, I expect that `\printglossary[style=long]` will work best. However, since this style relies on the `longtable` package, you'll need to be sure that `glossary` can access it.

Also, you might notice that the `style=long` option doesn't set glossary entry names in bold font as before.  If you still want that, just add `\renewcommand{\glsnamefont}[1]{\textbf{#1}}` to your document preamble to get it back again.

Comment: This is great. `style=index` worked best for me. Thanks!

Comment: For the record there is a `\printglossary` and a `\printglossaries` command, and those options only work with the former.

Answer (score 14):

Solution: use

```
\renewcommand*{\glsgroupskip}{}
```

Explanation: Abbreviations are bunched according to the starting letter. In your example, you can see this additional spacing is between the A-list & B-list and the B-list & C-list. This is the normal behavior of the glossaries package and is useful whenever the glossaries run to several pages. For smaller glossaries, it doesn't make a lot of sense.

Answer (score 7):

I solved this with **`\glsnogroupskiptrue`** before of `\printglossary`. I was using a  custom style based in `long` style and for some reason remained the spacing skip between groups and `\renewcommand*{\glsgroupskip}{}` do not worked at all.

Oddly, it seem that only `\glsnogroupskipfalse` appear in the manual (page 8) . It should be evident that this is a boolean option that must have a  opposite command, but it would have been better see it written.

Comment: As of now (v4.12, 2014-11-22), this command isn’t documented at all. I’m assuming that it’s no longer supported. But page 167 of the manual describes a specific solution for this case: either use `\newglossarystyle` or make the modifications after `\setglossarystyle`.

Answer (score 6):

**Solution:** Set to true the boolean **nogroupskip** when print the glossary via the command **printglossary**

```
\printglossary[nogroupskip=true]
```

I was looking for the same feature, the comment of @Konrad Rudolph helped me, I checked the manual and It was right there at the page 167 related to the command printglossary